# How to iterate a loop based on a user's input?

Tags: python, user-interface, user-input

I'm new here, but look here often for help. Anyways, I am trying to use tkSimpleDialog.askinteger() to ask for how many files the user needs to read into the program. I want to read the files in based on the integer that the user inputs in a for loop. I would index the file names f[1] through f[n] for the file names. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Please view below for an idea of what I am trying to get at:

```
def callback2():
    NumDates = tkSimpleDialog.askinteger("NDates", "How many dates are there?")
    for dates in NumDates:
        filename[dates] = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename() 
        dates = dates + 1
        filenameDates.append(filename)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `NumDates` is an integer, you're looking for the range function:

```
for dates in range(NumDates):
    ...
```

In python 2.x, you can use `xrange` instead.  This doesn't create an intermediate list so many people prefer it.  In python 3, `xrange` was renamed `range` and the former range function which returns a list was removed -- When the lists are small, I usually just use `range` for compatibility, but there exist tools (`2to3`) to take care of these details for you as well, so it really isn't a big deal either way.

*aside*

Also, as written, there really is no need for the `dates = dates + 1` (which is better written as `dates += 1` when necessary).

Comment: @user1620716: `dates` should probably be just `date` since represents just a one in the in `NumDates` range, which according to [PEP 8 -- [Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) really ought to be written `num_dates` otherwise it looks like the name of a class.